# How to access arm r0 to r15 register from firmware (c code)?

Tags: arm

From my firmware (arm based processor), I need to access value of arm cortex registers set r0 to r15. How can I access those registers? Firmware is using c code. Do I need to use inline assembler code? Any example code would be also helpful.

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you have attempted and where you got stuck? Any code would be useful.

Comment: You need probably inline asm, please name your compiler (which is probably gcc).

Comment: Given that any code you execute is, by necessity, already using those registers, you'd better explain what it is you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to access ARM registers and need to check what is the contain from firmware in case some crash happen. Hope requirement is clear now. I am using  GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors as compiler. If you can provide some idea with sample code will be helpful.

Comment: if you just want to see the registers for debugging , why dont you use a good debugger eg Emacs with GDB should give you access to those regs. ( But this might not be helpful after a cash, neither will any inline assembler code...! )

Comment: Note: the ARM has more that r0 to r15 as some registers are banked depending on mode.  This question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As [artless noise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880339/artless-noise) mentioned in the comments - some registers are banked. You didn't provide the type of CPU. Is it Corter Mx, Cortex Ax ?

Dumping all registers for crash logging is very simple but we need to consider an assumptions due to the lack of details in the question.

1. Firmware works in 'user' or 'system' mode and crash switches CPU into 'abort' mode

   ```
   STMDB   SP,     {R0-R14}^
   ```

   This will dump all registers into the 'abort' stack. Saved values could be access from the memory.
   `SP_abt` should be set appropriately in advance. Or similar option is to allocate a crash buffer and dump registers into particular memory region, rather than into stack.

   ```
   abort_handler:  
   push    {lr}                // LR_abt into 'abort' stack
   ldr     lr, =crash_buffer   // load address of crash log buffer
   stm     lr, {r0-r14}^       // Save *USER* R0-R14

   // do error handling if any
   pop     {lr}                // restore original LR_abt
   subs    pc, lr, #8          // return from ISR (optional)
   ```
2. Abort from non 'user'/'system' modes. The handling is pretty similar but to dump banked `SP` or `LR` or `Rx_fiq` you would need to

   - Load crash buffer address into not banked register
   - Switch into 'before-the-crash' mode. Original mode could be taken from `SPSR` register
   - Save banked registers
   - Go back to abort mode and finish error handling.